# mod_rewrite all pages to one script

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I tried using the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~user/sub/index.cgi [L]
```

but I am getting an error. This is intended to redirect all requests within my sub/ subdirectory (which is in a web docs on a server) to a single script, but it is not working. What would the correct rule be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/index.cgi [L]
```

Assuming that this `.htaccess` file is in the root of your `~user` directory.

For example, username `jay`:

```
Home directory: /home/jay
Web directory:  /home/jay/public_html (http://something/~user points here)
.htaccess file: /home/jay/public_html/.htaccess
script:         /home/jay/public_html/sub/index.cgi
```

---

Based on your comment, if your `.htaccess` file is in the `sub` directory, then you only need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cgi [L]
```

Comment: It's not, it's in the sub/ subdirectory. (edited to clarify)

Comment: Then you just need to do `index.cgi` with nothing else.

Comment: That does not seem to work. :( Specifically, I get a 404 error. So it is redirecting...but it must not be redirecting to the right place.

Comment: Then it's time to get debugging. A really easy way: make your .htaccess file garbage, do you get a 500 Internal Server Error? If not, your .htaccess is not being read at all. If you get the error, you'll need to check your `httpd.conf` for `AllowOverride`.

Comment: It is being used. I get a 500 internal server error with a bad .htaccess. And the 404 goes away when i point to an HTML file after disabling the .htaccess, but the 404 returns when I re-enable it, meaning it is being redirected after all. Just to the wrong place. Double checked spelling--index.cgi is the correct file.

Comment: Take a look at `RewriteBase`